# The google favicon is displaying beside my website name?

Tags: web, favicon

The title says it all. When I visit my website the google favicon is displaying beside my website title in the tab.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: In Chrome, if you open the Web Inspector (View > Developer > Developer Tools), select the Network panel, then reload the page, Chrome will show you all the resources it downloaded to construct the page. Did it happen to find a `favicon.ico` file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clear the cache or use another browser. Sometimes for example Google Chrome doesn't "want" to update the favicon.